# using title property in radio button element (HTML) for JS

Tags: javascript, html

There is well know property of HTML Radio button are "name, id, type, value), 
but For my project, I required one more additional information to be passed for JavaScript function, So I used "title" property. In my level best I checked (Ie8, Chrome now) there is no problem, Anyway I would like to get advice from experts. May I use this unusual title property for my production (Live site)... OR any other notable drawbacks behind that...Pls let I know... (I am in situation of satisfy both modern and classic browsers ... exemption for classic browser Ie6, and Ie7)

Comment: For *historical reasons* browsers will "accept" unknown element attributes and allow these to be accessed. But data-attributes (which are also accepted by older browsers for the same historic reasons) should be used as they are fully sanctioned by HTML5.

Comment: Note however that they are NOT valid in XHTML. So if you're using XHTML and want to stick to strict rules, you have to be more creative to solve that. CDATA blocks or additional namespaces could solve that issue in XHTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice, when you must provide data in your HTML elements, is [to use data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) :

> HTML5 is designed with extensibility for data that should be in the
>   HTML, but not visible. data-* attributes allow us to store extra
>   information on standard, semantic HTML elements without polluting the
>   class name.

For example :

```
<input name=a type=radio data-bing="bip">
```

Comment: There is no matter.. If I use HTML 5 :), As u know well I can't force my clients to use HTML 5 supporting browsers, I request you to share experience using strange 'title' property .. to avoid future probs)

Comment: All browsers, even the oldest ones, support the use of arbitrary attributes. Using `data-xxx` attributes reduces the risk of future incompatibilities and make your code more readable. That's why it's a best practice.